# Why is react native image background adding a gradient and darkening the original image?

Tags: react-native

I have this image saved on s3:
https://deinstruct-v4.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/background.png

I am trying to add it as a background image for a react native project and it keeps adding either a gradient on the top and bottom or outright darkening it as you can see in the 2 images below:
[image]

I was expecting the upscale since the image is made more for desktop than mobile, but I don't understand why it's being darkened.

My code is very simple.

```
import {View, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

// styles
import {css} from './landingStyles';

const Landing = props => {
    return (
        <View style={css.container}>
            <ImageBackground style={css.background} source={{uri: 'https://deinstruct-v4.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/background.png'}}>

            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Landing;
```

with landingStyles.js being:

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export const css = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: 'stretch',
        width:'100%',
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    image: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#FF0000',
        flex: 1,
    },
})
```

I added the border just to see where the image actual ends because with the black on the top/bottom I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. this may be issue with the. resizeMode.

```
import {ImageBackground, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

const Landing = props => {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      resizeMethod={'resize'}
      resizeMode={'cover'}
      style={css.background}
      source={{
        uri: 'https://deinstruct-v4.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/background.png',
      }}></ImageBackground>
  );
};

export default Landing;

export const css = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#FF0000',
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```